# Como executar uma aplicação Gtkmm C++ no Windows, sem MSYS2?

Tags: c, c++, gtk

Para utilizar(até aonde eu sei) as bibliotecas gráficas Gtkmm no Windows, eu tenho que instalar tais bibliotecas no MSYS2. Até ai tudo bem. Toda vez que faço a instalação e escrevo um arquivo C++ e compilo pelo g++ no MSYS2, é compilado tudo corretamente.

O problema é o seguinte: quando eu executo a aplicação pelo MSYS2, ou seja, ./programa.exe , a aplicação é executada corretamente. Mas quando eu não utilizo o MSYS2, ou seja, pego o mesmo executável programa.exe e abro ele com o duplo clique, é exibido uma mensagem de erro dizendo que falta dlls como libgtk-3.0-1.dll(e além de outras). Como posso resolver tal problema?

Desde já agradeço.

---

Acho que não será necessário. Achei na documentação oficial da Gnome os detalhes cruciais para o bom funcionamento do Gtk+ no Windows. Agradeço quem tiver a boa fé de me responder.

Link relativo: wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GtkmmOnWindows

Comment: Não editamos o título, marcamos a resposta correta

Answer (score -1):

Pode ser usado o seguinte procedimento para obter as DLLs nescessárias:

1. Baixar [Listdlls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls)
2. Deixar sua aplicação rodando
3. Abrir a janela do PowerShell no local onde está o Listdlls.exe
4. Usar o comando ./Listdlls.exe nomedaaplicação.exe
5. Copiar todos os caminhos listados para um arquivo de texto
6. Excluir todas as linhas que contem "C:\WINDOWS*"  em seu arquivo de
   texto
7. Deixar apenas as linhas que contem "C:\msys64* *.dll" em seu
   arquivo de texto
8. Abrir Msys2 Shell
9. Usar $ cp colar_todos_os_caminhos_das_dlls caminho_de_destino

Cuidados antes de usar o comando *$ cp*. Em seu arquivo de texto, mudar "\" para "/"  nos caminhos e tirar as quebras de linhas.